# How to remove last two characters every line of text file

Tags: php

How to remove the last two characters of every line of a text file? 
for example.
a.txt contains:

```
10081551
10081599
10082234
10082259
20081134
```

so the new txt file contain:

```
100815
100815
100822
100822
200811
```

thank you :)

Comment: Try regular expressions?

Comment: I don't know how to make the code on all the lines in the file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your expected output? Another file or just a string?

Comment: I want to make new text file, with new list like I explained...

Comment: Using explode and substr could possibly work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = file("long.txt");
$fp = fopen('short.txt', 'w');
foreach($content as $row)
{
    $shortened =  substr(trim($row) ,0,-2);
    fwrite($fp, $shortened."\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thank you! How I do it on all the lines in the file?

Comment: @JarumLarwa - I have updated my answer. It will read from long.txt and create a new version short.txt with the shortened rows

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = file("myfile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
array_walk(
    $data,
    function(&$value) {
        $value = substr($value, 0, -2);
    }
);
file_put_contents("myfile.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $data));
```

**EDIT**

The `file()` call loads the file into an `array`, with the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag stripping any `return` characters from each line, assigning it to $data; array_walk() then loops through each element of that array in turn (each line of the file) using the callback function to remove the last two characters of each lines. Finally, `imploding` the array back into a long string (re-inserting the new line characters for each element) before writing it back to file using `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file, convert the string to an array, and then remove the 2 last chars of every element of the array , and finally rewrite the file with new values

```
   $file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
   $lines = explode("\r\n", $file);
   foreach ($lines as $index => $line)
      $lines[$index] = substr($line, 0 , strlen($line)-2);
   file_put_contents("file.txt",implode("\r\n",$lines));
```

Comment: Yes, although missing braces from loops can be a source of bugs, especially for a beginner.